# Lookup a dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to lookup a dictionary of dictionaries and facing difficulty to do so.

Data is a dictionary and looks like this:

```
data={'CME':{u'JPY': 0.525, u'USD': 3.305, u'CNH': 4.805},
'EUREX':{u'USD': 3.305, u'GBP': 1.545, u'EUR': 0.375},
'GOODM':{u'KRW': 0.0},
'HKEX':{u'USD': 3.395, u'HKD': 3.565, u'CNH': 4.895},
'KIS':{u'KRW': 0.0},
'NLFX':{u'USD': 3.305},
'OSE':{u'JPY': 0.615},
'SGX':{u'JPY': 0.725, u'USD': 2.605, u'SGD': 2.575, u'CNH': 5.005, u'CNY': 0.0},
'TOCN':{u'JPY': 0.525}}
```

margins is a pandas dataframe and can be replicated this way:

```
margins = pd.DataFrame([{'balance_date': '2019-06-24', 'opp_pty_cd': 'GOODM','cur': 'KRW', 'amt':9714190.0,'acct': 30}, {'balance_date': '2019-06-24', 'opp_pty_cd': 'KIS','cur': 'KRW', 'amt':1858386321.,'acct': 30}])
```

Tried the following:

When i do this: `data['GOODM']['KRW']`, i get 0. However, when i do this: `data[margins['opp_pty_cd']][margins['cur']]`, i get this:

```
KRW    NaN
KRW    NAN
```

`margins['cur'].map(margins['opp_pty_cd'].map(data))`, still same data.

I am using the data frames data to lookup the dictionaries, which doesn't work.

Based on the comments below, tried to change the data to dataframe as `df_dict=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)`. But I cant still access the data when:

```
data[margins['opp_pty_cd']][margins['cur']]
```

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Looks like `margins['opp_pty_cd'] ` is a dictionary too. So you will have to access an entry from this dictionary: `margins['opp_pty_cd'][0]`.

Comment: nope they are not dictionaries, they are part of a dataframes.

Comment: could you post raw dictionnaries instead of a formatted table?

Comment: What libraries are you using? It doesn't look like what you have are plain dictionaries. You mention dataframes as well - are you using numpy or pandas? What's the type of `data`

Comment: @viraptor i m using pandas

Comment: posted how the data and margins are defined

Comment: sorry, edited both the dataframe and dictionary

Comment: Much better now, thanks! What is the desired output when you try `data[margins['opp_pty_cd']][margins['cur']]`?

Comment: desired output should be 0(for GOODM) and 0(KIS)

Answer (score 0):

```
dict={'CME':{u'JPY': 0.525, u'USD': 3.305, u'CNH': 4.805},
'EUREX':{u'USD': 3.305, u'GBP': 1.545, u'EUR': 0.375},
'GOODM':{u'KRW': 0.0},
'HKEX':{u'USD': 3.395, u'HKD': 3.565, u'CNH': 4.895},
'KIS':{u'KRW': 0.0},
'NLFX':{u'USD': 3.305},
'OSE':{u'JPY': 0.615},
'SGX':{u'JPY': 0.725, u'USD': 2.605, u'SGD': 2.575, u'CNH': 5.005, u'CNY': 0.0},
'TOCN':{u'JPY': 0.525}}

df_dict=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
print(df_dict)
       CME  EUREX  GOODM   HKEX  KIS   NLFX    OSE    SGX   TOCN
CNH  4.805    NaN    NaN  4.895  NaN    NaN    NaN  5.005    NaN
CNY    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  0.000    NaN
EUR    NaN  0.375    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
GBP    NaN  1.545    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
HKD    NaN    NaN    NaN  3.565  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
JPY  0.525    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN  0.615  0.725  0.525
KRW    NaN    NaN    0.0    NaN  0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
SGD    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  2.575    NaN
USD  3.305  3.305    NaN  3.395  NaN  3.305    NaN  2.605    NaN


print(df_dict['GOODM']['KRW'])
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient way, but for each row, you could use:

```
data[row.opp_pty_cd][row.cur]
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data={'CME':{u'JPY': 0.525, u'USD': 3.305, u'CNH': 4.805},
... 'EUREX':{u'USD': 3.305, u'GBP': 1.545, u'EUR': 0.375},
... 'GOODM':{u'KRW': 0.0},
... 'HKEX':{u'USD': 3.395, u'HKD': 3.565, u'CNH': 4.895},
... 'KIS':{u'KRW': 0.0},
... 'NLFX':{u'USD': 3.305},
... 'OSE':{u'JPY': 0.615},
... 'SGX':{u'JPY': 0.725, u'USD': 2.605, u'SGD': 2.575, u'CNH': 5.005, u'CNY': 0.0},
... 'TOCN':{u'JPY': 0.525}}
>>> margins = pd.DataFrame([{'balance_date': '2019-06-24', 'opp_pty_cd': 'GOODM','cur': 'KRW', 'amt':9714190.0,'acct': 30}, {'balance_date': '2019-06-24', 'opp_pty_cd': 'KIS','cur': 'KRW', 'amt':1858386321.,'acct': 30}])
>>> margins
   acct           amt balance_date  cur opp_pty_cd
0    30  9.714190e+06   2019-06-24  KRW      GOODM
1    30  1.858386e+09   2019-06-24  KRW        KIS
>>> for row in margins[['opp_pty_cd', 'cur']].itertuples():
...     print(data[row.opp_pty_cd][row.cur])
... 
0.0
0.0
```

There might be a better way if you convert `data` to a DataFrame.

Comment: thanks, how do u access the data when you change to dataframe?

Comment: did the change to dataframe but still can't access the data

Comment: @lakesh: The code above works when `data` is a dict of dicts. It won't work if you simply convert `data` to a DataFrame. You can simply leave it as it is.

Comment: i dont need to print the data but i need to multiply the data with an dataframe

Comment: i need to multiply the amt in margins dataframe with the value from data which matches the cur and opp_pty_cd

Comment: @lakesh: You can do whatever you want with `data[row.opp_pty_cd][row.cur]`, it's a float. `print` was just a way to show the results.

Comment: is there a way to present the data without the for loop?

Comment: @lakesh: I guess, possibly with `pandas.DataFrame.apply` or `data` as a DataFrame. Sorry, you'll have to do your homework, I cannot spend more time on this question today.